# Does dynamic dispatching decrease the cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: ruby, complexity-theory, refinements

Imagine the following method converting a boolean into an int:

```rb
def bool_to_int(bool)
  bool ? 1 : 0
end

bool_to_int(false) # => 0
bool_to_int(true) # => 1
```

Because of the conditional, the cyclomatic complexity score is two. Does the score drop to one by utilizing refinements in Ruby?:

```rb
module Extension
  refine FalseClass do
    def to_int; 0; end
  end

  refine TrueClass do
    def to_int; 1 end
  end
end

using Extension

false.to_int # => 0
true.to_int # => 1
```

In other words; does dynamic dispatching reduce the cyclomatic complexity score or are we just hiding the complexity by letting Ruby do the “heavy lifting”?

Comment: Apart from the cyclomatic complexity, you should probably not override the `to_int` method. This method should only be implemented by objects who resemble integers at all times and for all usages, i.e. which are whole numbers in their own right. Usually, you would only define `to_i` here which is used for explicit conversion, e.g. of Strings.

Comment: How do you define "cyclomatic complexity"? I'm not asking this to annoy you, but because the answer to your question depends on how you define cyclomatic complexity. If you define cyclomatic complexity to ignore dynamic dispatch, then it will ignore dynamic dispatch. If you define cyclomatic complexity to not ignore dynamic dispatch, then it will not ignore dynamic dispatch. The second question is: cyclomatic complexity *of what*? `bool_to_int`? `FalseClass#to_int`? `TrueClass#to_int`? The whole program?

Comment: Note that McCabe defined cyclomatic complexity only graph-theoretically, based on the control-flow graph, so not only does it depend on how you define it, but also on how you build the control-flow graph. And lastly, note that McCabe designed this metric for Fortran, so yet another question is whether it even can be applied to Ruby at all.

Answer (score 2):

Cyclomatic complexity is based on the nodes and edges available in them. By implementing dynamic dispatching, you are just implementing conditions in a different way.

So, the cyclomatic complexity stays constant.

**Edit based on the below comments**.

Yes, the cyclomatic concept is bound tightly with conditional statements. Reducing if/else statements results in less cyclomatic complexity. But the paths are constants. But now they are more isolated and not based on the conditions.

So I feel, the answer should be, Yes, the complexity gets reduced if you are successful in removing the conditional statements. But paths are constants.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any source that backs up your statement?

Comment: I concluded this based on the concept of Cyclomatic Complexity. We consider edges, nodes, connected components.

Comment: The tools I used tells me that the refinements impl. has a lower complexity than the if/else version.

Comment: Yes, the cyclomatic concept is bound tightly with conditional statements. Reducing if/else statements results in less cyclomatic complexity. But the paths are constants. But they are more isolated and not based on the conditions.

So I feel, the answer should be, Yes, the complexity gets reduced if you are successful in removing the conditional statements. But paths are constants.

Thanks for the reply though. I am too learning from these conversations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! That makes sense.